On the Rationalization of Finite Groups
Let $\Gamma$ be the countable set of finite groups identifying isomorphic ones (formal details below). Then, the direct product and the subgroup relation gives $(\Gamma,\times,\leq)$ the structure of an ordered monoid where $1\in\Gamma$ is the identity and the bottom element. Also, observe that we have the homomorphism of ordered monoids $O:\Gamma\to\mathbb{N}^+$ that asigns to each group its order.
Now, since $(\Gamma,\times)$ is an abelian monoid, we can consider its Grothendieck group $\Gamma^\sharp:=G(\Gamma)$ so that now it makes sense to talk about the reciprocal of a finite group $G^{-1}$ (not to be confused with $\{g^{-1}:g\in G\}=G$) satisfying $G\times G^{-1}=1$. Also, since $\Gamma$ satisfies the cancellation property $A\times C=B\times C\Rightarrow A=B$
, $\Gamma^\sharp$ is non-trivial. My question is the following.

Q: Has $\Gamma^\sharp$ been studied before? Is there some interesting interpretation of $G^{-1}$ other than as a mere formality? It would certainly be interesting if objects like $\Sigma_n^{-1}$ could induce some sort of "action".

Now I'm going to point out some structure that I think comes naturally with $\Gamma^\sharp$. First, we can extend the partial order $\leq$ to $\Gamma^\sharp$ as $$G_1\times H_1^{-1}\leq G_2\times H_2^{-1}\iff G_1\times H_2\leq G_2\times H_1$$
Also, since we can view $O:\Gamma\to\mathbb{N}^+$ as $O:\Gamma\to\mathbb{Q}^+$, by the universal property, we can extend it as $O:\Gamma^\sharp\to\mathbb{Q}^+$ giving a group epimorphism $O(G\times H^{-1})=O(G)/O(H)$ that is again monotonous. Moreover, we can endow $\Gamma^\sharp$ with a topology considering the initial topology induced by $O:\Gamma^{\sharp}\to(\mathbb{Q}^+,\tau)$. That is, $\tau_O=\{O^{-1}(U):U\in\tau\}$ which is the coarsest topology that makes $O$ continuous. This gives $(\Gamma^\sharp,\times,\tau_O)$ the structure of a topological group.
Note as well that the map $\Gamma\times\Gamma\to\Gamma^\sharp$ given by $(G,H)\mapsto G\times H^{-1}$ doesn't really extend the classical notion of quotient group since, for example, $C_4\times C_2^{-1}\neq C_4/C_2=C_2$.

Consider the set $X=\{S\leq\Sigma_{\mathbb{N}}:|S|\text{ is finite}\}$. By Cayley's Theorem, for every finite group $G$ there is some $S_G\in X$ such that $G\cong S_G$. So we can define $\Gamma:=X/\cong$. Then, it is easy to check that the following definitions are well-defined for $[S_1],[S_2]\in\Gamma$

We define $[S_1]\times[S_2]=[S_1\times S_2]$
We define $[S_1]\leq[S_2]$ as $\exists S_1'\leq S_2:S_1\cong S_1'$
We define $O([S_1])=|S_1|$


$\Gamma^{\sharp}$ is free abelian; if you use Krull-Schmidt, we can obtain a set $\Gamma'$ consisting precisely of the indecomposable factors of each group in $\Gamma$. Then $\Gamma^{\sharp}$ is a subgroup of $(\Gamma')^{\sharp}$, but $(\Gamma')^{\sharp}$ is the free abelian group on $\Gamma'$, as $(\Gamma',\times)$ is  the free monoid on $\Gamma'$.  For the $\Gamma$ in your final paragraph, you just get the free abelian group on the indecomposable groups.

@ArturoMagidin, so that means that $(\Gamma^\sharp,\times)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}^+,\cdot)$ as a free abelian group of countably infinite rank since there are countably infinite finite indecomposable groups. Right? Then, the topology $\tau_O$ is simply the topology induced by a group epimorphism $O:\mathbb{Q}^+\to\mathbb{Q}^+$. However, I wonder if the canonical structure of $\Gamma^\sharp$ has some sort of interpretation as a generalization of finite groups besides mere formalization, e.g., $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^4$ but it has a much richer interpretation.

Yes, you just get the positive rationals.
